# Kohana URL Confusion

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

My bootstrap.php file looks like this, and all code is embed in welcome controller->action_index.

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/kohana/',
    'index' => 'index.php'
));
```

Okay if I put the following in in action_index

```
form::open('test');
```

the action is **/kohana/index.php/test**.
So links appear to be absolute to your root install location, accept when I embed links in action_index index.php!!!

```
html::anchor('controller');
```

the href is **/kohana/controller** not */kohana/index.php/controller*.

Now if I put

```
url::site('controller');
```

the returned value is **/kohana/index.php/controller**.

So I figured I would just use

```
html::anchor(url::site('controller'));
```

But href is now equal to **http://localhost/kohana/kohana/index.php/controller**.

What in the world is going on, and how do I fix it?

Kohana url system seems well unintuitive and wrong.

Comment: DO you need the index.php or can you go without?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu with apache and mysql installed. On my server I have htacess but not on localhost. I can't do a url rewrite without htaccess but I could install it.

Comment: Change the line to `'index' => false` to make it all the same

Comment: To make what all the same?  For index.php to be removed I need htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is some kind of bug in `HTML::anchor` implementation.

This happens because of 127th line of `html.php` (v3.1.2)

```
$uri = URL::site($uri, $protocol, $index);
```

In this line `$index` value is `FALSE` according to the default `anchor` function value:

```
public static function anchor($uri, $title = NULL, array $attributes = NULL, $protocol = NULL, $index = FALSE)
```

So all you can do now is - to pass manually 5th argument as `true` like:

```
html::anchor('controller', null, null, null, true);
```

or extend `Kohana_HTML` with custom class like:

```
class HTML extends Kohana_HTML
{
    public static function anchor($uri, $title = NULL, array $attributes = NULL, $protocol = NULL, $index = TRUE)
    {
        return parent::anchor($uri, $title, $attributes, $protocol, $index);
    }
}
```

or to fill a bug on [kohana bugtracker](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana3/issues) so ko devteam decide what to do.

Comment: If it isn't specified then it should read the config settings. I think this is a bug.

Comment: @pedro_sland: indeed it definitely is. But as a temporary solution we can use extending hack ;-)